# Error Java invalid directory

Tags: java, gradle, build

Im using `ubuntu 16.04`, and when I try to compile my app using gradle it shows an error.
 I have no idea how to fix it.

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/bin/java

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

Running **java -version** show this

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-0ubuntu1.16.04.2-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Comment: What does the `/usr/bin/java` directory contain ?

Comment: And why have you set your JAVA_HOME to the path of the binary `java` instead of the location where Java is actually installed to?

Comment: @Berger This is not a directory.

Comment: guys I really have no idea why

Comment: `/usr/bin` either contains actual binary files or symlinks to binary files in their installed directory. For example `ls -l /usr/bin/java` would  tell you where it links to.

Comment: @PenAndPapers : type `whereis java` , the JAVA_HOME has to be the installation directory of a JDK .

Comment: @Berger it shows /usr/bin/java /etc/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz

Comment: @Tom it's a symlink that points to /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java*

Comment: Then you now know where Java is installed to: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`.

Comment: I've edited /etc/environment and added JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64", then source /etc/environment but still it shows same error

Comment: it works now, I had to run source /etc/enviroment on same terminal tab where I'm running my build command. Thanks @Tom

Comment: Since this would belong to SuperUser anyway, I would delete it here.